# How to set every preview upload video of mine to half of the duration time using React?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

I have a component to create an episode and upload a video with it.

I tried to use the ref of the video every time I upload it, but I only get the `<video>` tag instead of the `<video>` property. I want that every time I upload a video, it'll get the total duration and then split it in half, then assign that number to the currentTime of the video. It's like the preview image before uploading it, so I want to preview the middle of the video.

But when I console.log the `videoRef.current`, all I get is the `<video>`

Here's my code, I'm stuck at the useRef and trying to advance through it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

function FilmAddEpisode() {
    const { _id } = useParams()

    const videoRef = useRef()
    const [episodeName, setEpisodeName] = useState("")
    const [selectVideo, setSelectVideo] = useState()
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectVideo) {
            let objectUrlImage = URL.createObjectURL(selectVideo)
            setPreview(objectUrlImage)
        } else if (!selectVideo) setPreview(undefined)
    }, [_id, selectVideo])

    const handleEpisodeName = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target
        setEpisodeName(value)
    }

    const onSelectVideo = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!e.target.files || e.target.files.length === 0) {
            setSelectVideo(undefined)
            return
        }
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        setSelectVideo(file)
    }

    if (videoRef.current) {
        let videoTotalDuration = videoRef.current.duration
        // I get NaN here, because whenever I pressing upload and select a video, the videoRef.current return
        // the <video> tag instead of its property
        console.log("Video ref: ", videoRef.current)
        console.log("Video duration: ", videoTotalDuration)
        // If I can get video property, then I can assign currentTime to half of video duration 
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="add-episode-section">
                <div className="episode-name-holder">
                    <label htmlFor="episode-name">Episode name:</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="episodeName"
                        id="episodeName"
                        placeholder="Enter film name"
                        value={episodeName}
                        onChange={handleEpisodeName}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="episode-video-upload">
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        name="file"
                        id="file_up"
                        onChange={onSelectVideo}
                    />
                    <div className="preview-episode">
                        {selectVideo && (
                            <video
                                src={preview}
                                alt=""
                                width="40%"
                                height="auto"
                                ref={videoRef}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default FilmAddEpisode
```

Because the videoRef.current is a `<video>` tag instead of a `video` property, it leads to I can't get any video property.

[image: image example]

Where did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if your problem is solved but you need to add a "load" event listener on the video tag, when it fires it means the video's metadata is ready and you can seek within the video time,

Comment: Thanks, @VC.One, I add `onLoadedData` to the video tag, then used the `ref` in there and it work.